# Symfony Doctrine: check connection to a database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, php-8, symfony6

Since a while checking a connection to a database in a controller was working fine doing the following:

```
$em->getConnection()->connect();
$connected = $em->getConnection()->isConnected();
```

But I now have a deprecation:

> php.INFO: User Deprecated: Public access to Connection::connect() is deprecated.

How should I test my database connection now ?

Comment: Deprecation isn't an error. It's just a warning that this will _become_ an error _in a future version of the software_. Your code should still work.

Comment: @ADyson Yep, I know that and I want to get rid of that deprecation :)

Comment: Well you can turn off the deprecation warnings (I wouldn't really recommend this, as you'll forget about them!), or make it only appear in a log file. Or yeah you can alter the code. In most cases a deprecation message ought to suggest an alternative approach, but this one doesn't. I'm not personally familiar enough with symfony to suggest what you are supposed to do. Is there anything in the symfony documentation for the connect() function which talks about it?

Comment: @ADyson Unfortunately I did not yet found anything in the doc.

Comment: Let see if getWrappedConnection instead of connect works.

Comment: Don't, getWrappedConnection is also deprecated: https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/5037/files

Comment: @DylanKAS yes indeed, I finaly used getNativeConnection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a deprecation notice when connection is used outside the library:

```
Deprecation::triggerIfCalledFromOutside(
            'doctrine/dbal',
            'https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/4966',
            'Public access to Connection::connect() is deprecated.',
        );
```

You need to use `getNativeConnection()` instead (which is from the same [Connection class](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/3.7.x/src/Connection.php#L1660))

```
$em->getNativeConnection()->isConnected();
```

[You can read the PR containing those changes.](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/5037)